# Leaflet JS polygon on a same map

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, leaflet

I use Leaflet JS, and I need same polygon on a one map

Now:
[image]

I need:

[image]

Thank's for your help!

If I set the noWrap:true on the tileLayer or the worldCopyJump:true I get:

[image]

Fiddle – [jsfiddle.net/paRxe/5](http://jsfiddle.net/paRxe/5/)

```
 var map = L.map('mapId',{
            center: [35.67989, 139.76463],
            zoom: 2,
            // worldCopyJump: true,
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 1,
            // reuseTiles: true,
            // continuousWorld: trie
            // reuseTiles: true,
            // continuousWorld: true  
            worldCopyJump: true       
          }
        );
```

Comment: What happens if you set the `noWrap` option on the `tileLayer`?

Comment: I update my question.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: What about [`worldCopyJump` on the map](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-worldcopyjump)? [A jsfiddle would be great too](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Fiddle – http://jsfiddle.net/paRxe/5/ @CG_FD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 polygons are actually part of a multipolygon, forming a single feature.

You could use Turf.js for example, in order to 1) translate one of the part by 360 degrees, and 2) merge those 2 parts. Then record the new feature geometry to replace your current GeoJSON data.

For step 1), you should also be able to use directly Leaflet with `latLng.wrap()` method.

Comment: Thank's a lot dude for your help!